# export an array with dynamic array name

Tags: bash, shell, sh

For suppose there is a code

```
comp="LP"
n_names="abc456.com,def123.com,wxy098.com"
IFS=',' read -r -a n_split_list <<< "$n_names"
```

Now I want to export the **n_split_list** array with the following variable format. Remember comp need not always be "LP" . It changes based on argument given to the script.

```
export "$comp"_list="${n_split_list[@]}"
```

but the problem is coming while exporting ( only first item of the array is getting exported )
Please help!

Comment: `"$comp"_list=` How would you use the variable later?? You can't do `echo "${${comp}_list[@]}"` - that's invalid. What is the point? `Remember comp need not always be "LP"` sure, but why would you _want_ to create a variable with the name of other variable? What are the array and comp meant to _represent_? How are they meant to be used?

Comment: @KamilCuk It is actually possible to do: `var="${comp}_list[@]"; printf '%s\n' "${!var}"`.

Comment: You can not _export_ an array. Only variables and functions.

Comment: Due to how `@` works, your command is equivalent to `export "$comp"_list="${n_split_list[0]}" "${n_split_list[1]}" "${n_split_list[2]}"`.

Comment: You could switch to `*`, which would make `LP_list` an ordinary space-delimited list of domain names, but that would defeat the purpose of using an array in the first place (and as dan points out, you cannot export an array itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your values may contain whitespaces, you may use `read` again with dynamic variable name and comma as `IFS`:

```sh
comp="LP"
n_names="abc456.com,def123.com,w xy098.com"
IFS=',' read -r -a n_split_list <<< "$n_names"

IFS=, read -ra ${comp}_list < <(printf '%s,' "${n_split_list[@]}")

# check content of new array
declare -p ${comp}_list

declare -a LP_list=([0]="abc456.com" [1]="def123.com" [2]="w xy098.com")
```

[Working Demo](https://ideone.com/sB5Axk)

Comment: but comp need not always be "LP" it can change. in that case?

Comment: syntax error near unexpected token `<' -- for 4th line of your code.

Comment: Check [working demo](https://ideone.com/sB5Axk) May be you have older bash version